# React Redux cant get reducer to pick up actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been learning redux & react and am building a todo list. I've been reading and looking at different articles but cant figure out what I'm missing in my setup.

Currently you can add a todo via the input. On pushing enter it sends a `addTodo` action with the todo text.

I'm expecting the reducer to see the action type and update the state but it never does. What am I missing?

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducer.js';
import TodoList from './containers/container.js';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoList />
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

**actions.js**

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

export function addTodo(text) {
  console.log('action addTodo', text);
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    payload: {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      text: text
    }
  };
}
```

**TodoListComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoComponent from './TodoComponent.jsx';
import { addTodo } from '../actions/actions.js'

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { todos } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Add todo' onKeyDown={this.onSubmit} />
        <ul>
          {todos.map(c => (
            <li key={t.id}>
              <TodoComponent todo={t} styleName='large' />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    const input = e.target;
    const text = input.value;
    const isEnterKey = (e.which === 13);

    if (isEnterKey) {
      input.value = '';
      addTodo(text);
    }
  }

}
```

**TodoComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './style.css';

export default class TodoComponent extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { todo } = this.props;

    return (
      <div styleName='large'>{todo.text}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default CSSModules(TodoComponent, styles);
```

**container.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoList from '../components/TodoListComponent.jsx';
import { addTodo } from '../actions/actions.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      todos: state
   }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      addTodo: text => dispatch(addTodo(text))
   }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { List, Map } from 'immutable';

const init = List([]);

export default function(todos = init, action) {

  console.log('reducer action type', action.type);

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      console.log('ADD_TODO');
      return todos.push(Map(action.payload));
    default:
      return todos;
  }
}
```

Comment: In `TodoListComponent.jsx`, you should use the `addTodo` passed in `props` via `connect`

Comment: As a side note to the answers below, when working in Redux your reducers should always be returning a new instance of state, not manipulating the current state so rather than `return todos.push(Map(action.payload));` which alters the current array you should use `return todos.concat(Map(action.payload));` which will return a new array from your current state & the action payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TodoListComponent` you are importing your actions directly from your actions file, but in fact you want to use the action that you map to dispatch and pass as property in the container. That explains why you see logs from the actions, but not from reducer, as the action is never dispatched to the store.

So your `TodoListComponent` should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoComponent from './TodoComponent.jsx';

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { todos } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Add todo' onKeyDown={this.onSubmit} />
        <ul>
          {todos.map(c => (
            <li key={t.id}>
              <TodoComponent todo={t} styleName='large' />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    const input = e.target;
    const text = input.value;
    const isEnterKey = (e.which === 13);

    if (isEnterKey) {
      input.value = '';
      this.props.addTodo(text);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. That worked, your answer was missing the ` onKeyDown={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}` which was suggested in @opheman answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoComponent from './TodoComponent.jsx';

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const { todos } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Add todo' onKeyDown={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} />
        <ul>
          {todos.map(c => (
            <li key={t.id}>
              <TodoComponent todo={t} styleName='large' />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    // use the addTodo passed via connect
    const { addTodo } = this.props;
    const input = e.target;
    const text = input.value;
    const isEnterKey = (e.which === 13);

    if (isEnterKey) {
      input.value = '';
      addTodo(text);
    }
  }

}
```